# Eclipse for web development

Tags: eclipse, plugins, web-development

I'm looking for a better solution for developing with JavaScript, CSS and HTML instead of using the old fashioned text editors.
When I started to develop android applications I was kind of sceptical about Eclipse and this "new school IDE whatever" but after short time my only thought become: How did I worked successfull in the past without this nice stuff like refactoring, project wide search etc.

As it also happens that I've to support our web developers especially in terms of JavaScript/jQuery implementation I'd be well happy to find a similar solution as I've got for Java/Android dev.
I think that the ability to create "web project" similar to "android projects" is giving everything a little bit of a frame.

A quick google research pops up the following three "plugins":

- [Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosm5)
- [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)
- [JSDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT)

However, I'm still feeling kind of insecure with installing additional Eclipse "stuff" so the ideal solution would be easy to handle like adding another repo to the marketplace and download the stuff from there.

If all these words been to confusing, just think of it as "how the heck can I get a nice Eclipse environment for web developing?"

I think a good answer would point out some of the differences between multiple solutions and maybe provide an easy installation guide (in-eclipse solution give bonus points).

Comment: Maybe [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)? Based on Eclipse, but made for web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried them all, and I ended up using [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (which supports NodeJS as well as everything you have mentioned).

It is far superior to Eclips, Aptana and Netbeans, so if you can afford it, it is very much worth the money.